# How to restrict interface property type to subset of a declared enum?

Tags: typescript, enums

I have an external module declaring a bunch of enums:

```
declare enum A {
B,
C,
D
}
```

I am then creating interfaces based off of these enums:

```
interface ISomeProps {
someProp: A
}
```

However, in some cases I want to restrict the type of `someProp` to just a subset of `A`, for example:

```
interface ISomeRestrictedProps {
restrictedProp: A.B | A.C
}
```

Is this possible to do without declaring a new enum with the subset of cases (which is how I am currently doing this)?

I've tried using `Extract` or union types but I can't reference the enum cases on the declared enum because I get a TS error:

```
enum has members with initializers that are not literals.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way around this is to declare the enum differently.

One way to do this is quite verbose but acts a lot like a declared enum with unknown values.  True enums in TypeScript add a lot of named types and values with a small amount of code, so to simulate it manually we need a lot of lines.  The general technique is to declare a value and a type for each of `A`, `A.B`, `A.C`, and `A.D`, and to do it in such a way as to treat the types of each enum value as different from each other without knowing what they actually are:

```
declare namespace A {
  interface _B { readonly __nominal: unique symbol; }
  export type B = _B & number;
  export const B: B;

  interface _C { readonly __nominal: unique symbol; }
  export type C = _C & number;
  export const C: C;

  interface _D { readonly __nominal: unique symbol; }
  export type D = _D & number;
  export const D: D;
}
type A = A.B | A.C | A.D;
```

In the above, the `{ readonly __nominal: unique symbol }` serves as a [branding](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) technique using [unique symbols](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#unique-symbol) to make TypeScript treat each of `A.B`, `A.C`, and `A.D` as *nominally* typed and therefore distinct types from each other despite having the "same" structure.  This is lying to the compiler a little bit, since obviously at runtime `A.C` will not have a property named `__nominal`, but as long as you ignore this it should act fine.

Let's make sure: if you have a variable of the full enum type, you can assign any member to it:

```
let a: A = A.B; // okay
a = A.C; // okay
a = A.D; // okay
```

But if you have a variable of just one of the member types, you can't assign other ones:

```
let b: A.B = A.B; // specifically only A.B
b = A.C; // error! A.C not assignable to A.B
b = A.D; // error! A.D not assignable to A.B
```

Now your types are allowed:

```
interface ISomeRestrictedProps {
  restrictedProp: A.B | A.C;
}
```

And behave more or less like you want:

```
const i: ISomeRestrictedProps = {
  restrictedProp: A.B // okay
};
i.restrictedProp = A.C; // okay
i.restrictedProp = A.D; // error! D not assignable to B | C
```

[Link to branded-enumlike code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEA7KBbEBnADlMCCC8A3gFDzwCWiALiDAGY4ID6AQkfHFMAPaIQCe8Jk0TcUlKBABc8AK6JyAR1kJ0-FACNuEANzwAvqXggAHpm4wq8Kv0wI2AXiFsAZElmbaOo6fOX4YLzoViwyLN5GlDT0jEIAwuycPHyCwqLiyNJyCsqq6lq6Bj5mFlY2dvAJTkwJbogeGl7FflaBiMGVMnERZFG0DLhCACKJIFy8AkIiYhJZ8koq8Gqa2nqGZL6l1rYII9UjdQ1NGyX+bR1DMkPehuX48E54AHRsAD7wzwnvz9fExBAgKxQGQER4vPQAegh8G4AGsoPxiFAHh8nt14FCYfDEciwdcMdC4Qi-gCrBoQS8Uc9wgSlnYwOQ6OQwJJJhNBNTiBoqWjIdDaDALABCVEJURA9DocgAc2QGgB1m4qJYXJ5+MxAuFqJG4vgUElMrlCqoSs5xD6MUGAEkAMpiEAABUFmHQRCM6HtTu4mBBNz+FoGCFt9oAShgqDBmTRgF6XW6yHBgpGwNHYxS3qK-cRzlZyDJg2gw0moyAY87XU4SAnw8nU8707SiYj9N5yE9ExGS2XvTz0Zim+b2zWu7G1XzjDBBTARTruBKpbKoPKECb4Bm4sQgA)

---

Similarly, you can just do what @TitianCernicova-Dragomir [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56894485/2887218) and give values to the enums.  They don't really have to be the *actual* values, as long as they are distinct from each other and you don't make the mistake of treating them as the real values:

```
declare enum A {
  B = 0xbbbbb, // dummy value for B
  C = 0xccccc, // dummy value for C
  D = 0xddddd  // dummy value for D
}
```

Again you are lying to the compiler about the exact values, but as long as you just ignore the exact values and don't write code that cares about the exact values, it should be fine.  The subsequent code should all work as you expect (and I'm not going to repeat the above code... you can see how it acts in the following link)

[Link to dummy-val-enum code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEIB2BXAtvAgvA3gKHngCF4BeeABgA8AjOugGngHpn5h00BPeANyggoEAMwD2MYgXgBhMpSphFipq3ace-QSPEypAETnVgx44VUc03PgKHwxEvXgC+ePBBAAXeFABcWOZgAdEQA3CxsogDWUFx4UAGB0mGqUTFxCXrJEdGxbp7wNH5BJOTFWfAAzgAO4ACWwrVgAhA8okgtWMF4NAlJ4YgwMOIAhJ2ySKJeUBUVtQDmSFA07vAeop1E3RnlIIMjnQYTUzPzi8sIaxuutUgeu8JQYAgAkgDKomggAApDVRW4UgqH2+vyKIWc11u90eL3enwASiAKh4YI07sAfqI-gDCHBkaiwOjMVUisF4AAfMbglx4MBtZHwWp+N7AxH4tEgDG-f7kfC4pEojlcrGkkgpHLOcG1QJ4wWEznE3rlVKxaWyglE37bfq7IYwUaHSbeE4LJYrS4kSnSPBAA)

---

In both of those you are lying a little bit to the compiler... the former method is verbose but doesn't pretend you know the numeric values of the enum, whereas the latter method is simpler but possibly runs more of a risk of an unwary developer thinking the dummy values are actual values.

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Wow, thanks for the thorough response. Learned a lot :) Sounds like there isn't a great way to do this... but going forward I'm not sure enums are what we should be using in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach of using a union is correct. The problem is with the enum declaration. Typescript will not let you use union of enum members unless it knows the values of those enums. Unsure why though , tracked it down to this [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/9407) which states this rule explictly:

> When each member of an enum type has either an automatically assigned value, an initializer that specifies a numeric literal, or an initializer that specifies a single identifier naming another enum member, that enum type is considered a union enum type. The members of a union enum type can be used both as constants and as types, and the enum type is equivalent to a union of the declared member types.

Since the enum is declared it will not have values automatically assigned and since there are no explicit values either it will just not be treated as a union of enum members.

This will work, but I'm not sure if changing the enum definition is an option:

```
declare enum A {
    B = 0,
    C = 1,
    D = 2
}

interface ISomeRestrictedProps {
    restrictedProp: A.B | A.C
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! Unfortunately, changing the declaration isn't an option as we are actually downloading a file from a server which contains the actual values for the enum. That seems unfortunate... I'll leave the question open for a while to see if anyone has any other ideas and if not, I'll accept this answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

For my use-case, the `Exclude` utility type worked perfectly for this.

```js
export enum TransactionSet {
  "NormalTransactions" = "NormalTransactions",
  "TransactionsWithErrors" = "TransactionsWithErrors"
}

type ActionPayload = { transactionsSet: Exclude<TransactionSet, TransactionSet.TransactionsWithErrors> };

const action1: ActionPayload = { transactionsSet: TransactionSet.NormalTransactions }; // OK
const action2: ActionPayload = { transactionsSet: TransactionSet.TransactionsWithErrors }; // Not assignable
```

Or for the inverse, use the `Extract` helper type